# Given this preamble, what font would be used?

Tags: fonts, preamble

Given the following code sample, what font would LaTeX actually use? I've looked in various places, but the help on fonts seems too cunning to be understood. This is definitely a different question from some of the other suggested questions that TeX.SE suggests.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Latin Modern Roman font. Compile your preamble with a minimal document using pdflatex and view the Document Properties. You'll see LMRoman12-Bold and LMRoman12-Regular under the Fonts tab...

Comment: With Euler Script for script maths.

Comment: As it stands, I don't really see this question being of much general use. Would you consider editing it so that it might be more generally useful to both yourself and others? (Will you ask here which font you'll get every time you use a new preamble? What don't you understand about the preamble you have? Why, for example, did you think that `graphicx` or `enumerate` might affect the font?)

Comment: More specifically, you will get postscript type 1 versions of Latin Modern (provided you have the package installed, of course). You may also get some characters from Computer Modern depending on the content of your document.

Comment: @PaulGessler This is not a duplicate of that question because that question is about identifying fonts from the compiled image/document, whereas this is about predicting the fonts which will be used. You don't need to compile to figure out what will be used, assuming font availability on the system, of course.

Comment: @cfr I don't agree that it's about predicting, because the OP's comment indicates that compiling the document and viewing the Document Properties was an acceptable solution. Either way, as you've stated in earlier comments, this is not a generally useful question, and the OP has not edited it to be more general after some months.

Comment: @PaulGessler I agree it should be closed. But the question is not a duplicate of that question. (Even if an acceptable answer is a duplicate of an acceptable answer to that question.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a one-off query which does not relate to any general, methodological or procedural insight as stated.